# How to create a second persistent store in Core Data for sync with CloudKit using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, synchronization, cloudkit

I am writing a simple app using Core Data, and I want to sync data through CloudKit. The way I thought is: add the "NSManagedObjectContextDidSave" observer for Core Data, when the context saved, it also launch the sync function for CloudKit. If upload succeed, there is no more work, if upload failed, I want to save the changed objects into a second persistent store for later sync again.

So, my question is how can I save those changed objects into a second store in Core Data? Is this way possible to implement the sync function?

I did some search the about the related questions, but few can meet my requirement.
I am a freshman for iOS, my first thought is parent/child context, after search and study, I found this is not the right way, what I need is two separate databases, when I save the uploaded failed objects into syncDB( another just named it localDB, the default one), it should have no effect on localDB, when next time sync succeed, the uploaded objects will be delete from the syncDB, so the best state is syncDB keeps empty, which means all changed objects have been synced to the CloudKit.

Another issue I learn from search is we can't save relationship between different stores, but I do need this, for example, I have Car Entity, and it has a relation "category" to Category Entity, the inverse is "cars". Does this relationship can also save into the second store?

In summary, my situation is I need two stores which using the same Entities, one is "LocalDB" for normal use, another is "SyncDB" for CloudKit sync. I just begin learning iOS and swift, maybe my question is not good for stackoverflow, but this really puzzled me, I got stuck here for many days. Any help is appreciate, and any other sync solution is also welcome, thank you!

Comment: Rather than duplicating data, you'd be better off keeping track of which objects need to be uploaded. Maybe keep a list of managed object IDs.

Comment: Thank you Tom! Your advice give me an inspiration. I do not even need the second persistent store. My solution is I use "viewContext" to deal with user related entities, and also monitor that context's DidSave. And I add a new entity named SyncObjects (has two attributes "modelObjectID " and "modificationDate") using a new background context, I call it "SyncContext". So, when the user related entities has change, I upload them to the cloud, if upload failed, I save those IDs in SyncObjects entity in the SyncContext. Both contexts are using one persistent store. I really appreciated your help!